# cannot import DLL with Ctypes.cdll

Tags: python, dll, raspberry-pi, ctypes

I'm using Raspberrypi for the first time, I want to import a DLL file with python. 
I tried this in windows it works but on Raspberry I got this error,

" OSError :  Name.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

.txt
Hello,

I'm using Raspberrypi for the first time, I want to import a DLL file with python. 
I tried this in windows it works but on Raspberry I got this error,

" OSError :  Name.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

any Help please?

```
print(struct.calcsize("P")*8)
32
import os
os.chdir("/home/pi/Documents/sens2020")
from ctypes import *
import ctypes
my_dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("Sense2020Dll.dll")
```

Comment: Did you tried to writte the full path of the file? `my_dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("/home/pi/Documents/sens2020/Sense2020Dll.dll")`

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried it, I have this Error " OSError: path: invalid ELF header" !

Comment: This error means that the file was found. But the DLL could not be opened. Are you sure it is feasable to load a DLL on a Raspberrypi? Since DLL are made for Windows. Maybe you should create a .SO

Comment: is it possible to convert .dll to .so ?

Comment: I don't have the source code of the dll

Comment: Maybe you could uncompile it with some tools. But you won't get the exact source code. And maybe... maybe you could rebuild the project to generate a `.so`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the OS on your Raspberry pi is Windows, you should not try to load a `.DLL` file. They are designed to work only on Windows.

From recall, you can build a 32 & 64 bits `.DLL`. So keep an eye on how you build your `.DLL` and the Architecture of the Windows you are using.

For linux based, you will need a shared library `.so`. You will have to rebuild your project to create a `.so`.

If you don't have the source code of the `.DLL`, I think there's no direct way to convert dll's to SO.

Comment: What if I try to create a shared library.so with a function which call the .dll. is it possible ?

Comment: Linux and Windows are binary incompatible, sames goes for libraries. System calls are not the same. Maybe in near future windows will be able to run `.so` with their next built in Linux Kernel inside Windows. But I doubt the other way round

Comment: Maybe you could use Wine on your Rasberry Pi. Wine is kind of (but not really) an emulator for Windows on Unix systems. I have no clue if `DLL`s could run on this.

Comment: An other option would of been to install Windows 10 IoT on your Rasberry, but it still needs to have a `dll` build for ARM architecture and not 32 or 64 like our basic computers.

Comment: Thank you very much sir